# How to detect whether Android device is locked in portrait or landscape orientation

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

If in an Android device the auto rotate option is off - how can I check whether the user chose to lock the device in portrait or landscape mode?

I can't rely on the actual orientation that the device was in when the user changed the settings - in some devices (mostly phones) there is only portrait lock, which will be turned on even if the device is in landscape orientation.

I use this piece of code, but it returns only if the auto rotate is on or off, but not the actual lock orientation.

This for an app that is developed in Unity, so both Unity or Android native suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
private static bool DeviceAutoRotationIsOn()
{
    using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {
        var context = actClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        var systemGlobal = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$System");
        var rotationOn = systemGlobal.CallStatic<int>("getInt",
            context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"), "accelerometer_rotation");

        return rotationOn == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need for specific orientation like only portrait or landscape for your app then you can set it on manifest file  using android:screenOrientation .

Comment: RANAJEET BARIK -  Thanks, but I need to support both the portrait and the landscape orientations (and it's works fine as long as the device's auto rotate option is on). My only problem is to identify in which orientation the user locked the device when he disabled auto rotation option, so I will lock my app in the same orientation as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current orientation:

Kotlin

```
val display = (baseContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
val rotation = display.rotation
```

Java

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

Result could be:

```
Surface.ROTATION_0 
Surface.ROTATION_90 
Surface.ROTATION_180
Surface.ROTATION_270
```

90 and 270 for landscape

0 and 180 for portrait